# Number of ways of writing a sum of n numbers

Tags: combinatorics

Suppose we have some numbers A1, A2, A3 ..... An
How many ways can we write the addition A1 + A2 + A3 ... + An in different forms.

Like, **Ax + A3 + A4 + .... + An** is one of the forms where **A1 + A2 = Ax** summed up and written in place of the two numbers.

For example, let's say **2+2+2** which can be written as itself, **4+2**, **2+4** and **6** so there are **4** ways in this case.

I face some problems coming up with a combinatoric formula for questions like these. I would really like to know if there is a good way to approach these kinds of problems. Thank you :)

Update: For my query, I just want to know the number of ways if all the numbers A1 = A2 = ... = An = 2. I would like to know the answer to the generalized question too if possible.

Comment: What happens here: `1+2+3+4` can I write `4+2+4` (adding the 3 to the 1) or just `2+4+4` (adding the 1 to the 3). Or is this not possible because the numbers are not adjacent?

Comment: Yes all such possible combinations. You can add non adjacent numbers too

Comment: Should $2+2+2+2$ is $4+4=(A_1+A_2)+(A_3+A_4)$ be considered equal or different than $4+4=(A_1+A_3)+(A_2+A_4)$ ?

Comment: @zwim it will be considered same

Comment: Sorry, I wanted to introduce a quick update. For my query, the numbers are always 2 that is A1, A2, .... An are always 2 and as @zwim mentioned, The sum will be considered same. I thought generalizing the question will be better as its my first post here. Sorry for the inconvinience. Its still a valid question though and I would like to know the answer to it if its possible but for my case, consider every element as 2

Comment: Are all numbers positive? Non-negative? Real? Is $\frac 12 + \frac 12 + \frac 12 + \frac 12 + \frac 12 + \frac 12 + \frac 12 + \frac 12 + \frac 12 + \frac 12 + \frac 12 + \frac 12 = 6$ valid?

Comment: @an4s All numbers are non-negative integers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are $2^{n-1}$ ways to write $2n$ as ordered sums arising from combinations of $n$ 2s as you describe.

An equivalent problem connects to a known mathematical structure.  Rather than $n$ 2s, start with $n$ 1s.  Your examples summing to 6 correspond to $1+1+1$, $1+2$, $2+1$, and $3$.  These are called the (integer) compositions of 3.

For the $2^{n-1}$ formula, consider $n$ 1s lined up.  In each of the $n-1$ positions between the 1s, you can do one of two things: join to increase the current summand or cut (put a plus sign) to start a new summand.  (This is MacMahon's argument from *Combinatory Analysis*.)  Here's the correspondence for the compositions of 3:

1 J 1 J 1 ~ $3$

1 J 1 C 1 ~ $2+1$

1 C 1 J 1 ~ $1+2$

1 C 1 C 1 ~ $1+1+1$

So, for $n=5$ 2s in your problem, for instance, there are $2^{4} = 16$ different sums, the 16 compositions of 5 with each term doubled: 
\begin{gather*}
\{10, 82, 64, 622, 46, 442, 424, 4222, 28, 262, 244, 2422, 226, 2242, 2224, 22222\} \\
\sim \{5, 41, 32, 311, 23, 221, 212, 2111, 14, 131, 122, 1211, 113, 1121, 1112, 11111\}
\end{gather*}

Comment: I got it. Thank you!